# Detecting CSS animationend using jQuery on parent element only

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I have a CSS animation where I have 2 pieces animating. The first animation animates both pieces together, so the animation is on the parent element. The second animation only happens to one of the elements within the parent element. I am trying to detect the end of the parent element animation using the following code:

```js
$(function() {
    $(".animation-container").one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function () {
        alert('Animation complete');
    });
});
```

```css
.animation-container > div {
  display:block;
  background:#000;
  width:20px;
  height:30px;
}

.animation-container {
  animation:rotateOuter 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.animation-container .top {
  animation:rotateInner 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateOuter {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-20deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotateInner {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-30deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

However, this is firing twice, because it is detecting the `animationend` on the parent element, as well as the child element. Is there a way to make it so that it only detects the end of the animation for the parent element?

Comment: Why not just ignoring the first animation

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO not sure what you mean

Comment: Adding a counter so you know how many times an animation has stoped. An because you know your animation, you can trigger your code when your counter is at 2

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO great idea, that worked perfect. Feel free to add as answer if you would like the points!

Comment: happy it worked and thanks for the points jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a counter so you know how many times an animation has stoped. An because you know your animation, you can trigger your code when your counter is at 2

```js
$(function() {
    var animationCount = 0;
    $(".animation-container").one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function () {
        animationCount++
        if (animationCount === 2) {
          alert('Animation complete');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.animation-container > div {
  display:block;
  background:#000;
  width:20px;
  height:30px;
}

.animation-container {
  animation:rotateOuter 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.animation-container .top {
  animation:rotateInner 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateOuter {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-20deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotateInner {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-30deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```